# calling cformview child dialog from cdialog parent dialog

Tags: mfc, parent-child, cdialog

I have a parent `CDialog` dialog box which is supposed to call a `CFormView` child dialog. I know that, to call a `CDialog` dialog box, we use `DoModal()` function. Is there a similar function for `CFormView` as well to call it from anywhere?

Comment: I think we need more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 2 dialogs:
1. Cdialog dialog which is the main window.
2. CfromView child dialog which is called from the main dialog for auto-suggestive item search. This is implemented using the following code available at [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187753/Extended-CComboBox). This code uses Cfromview class for the implementation and I need to call it from the Cdialog main window. I hope this explains the issue.

Comment: sorry i am not able to explain it better. the point is to call a cformview child dialog from a cdialog main dialog.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. I only know how to embed a view into a dialog. Sorry.

Comment: okay. thanks for you reply though! but I don't completely understand what embedding means here. can you explain? It might help. Sorry, I am new to MFC.

Comment: Basically embedded means the view becomes part of the dialog itself like another control.

Comment: oh nice! I can use that. maybe that is what I am looking for. I didn't form my question properly earlier. can you explain how to embed them?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/article.php/c5007/Creating-a-View-on-a-Dialog.htm